# Some CMD command is unrecognized

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I tried to run a `CMD` file, unfortunately some of command like `clipup` is unrecognized, but it do recognized when I run the file out of the project.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(fileDirectory,"file.cmd");
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 'clipup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

Anybody can explain why and the possible fix?

Comment: And what's in `fileDirectory`? You should be using `Path.Combine` to combine path elements, otherwise you risk combining a string that doesn't end in the directory path separator with a filename and getting the wrong path, like `"C:\\Temp" + "file.cmd"` becomes `"C:\\Tempfile.cmd"`, not `"C:\\Temp\\file.cmd"`.

Comment: What is `clipup`?

Comment: And is the error that some of the statements *inside* the batch file is giving you that error? If so, then most likely you have a PATH outside that isn't available inside, are you using a thirdparty console/terminal window, or just `CMD.exe` ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - It's directory on where the file is stored or can be access.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - Just a CMD no thirdparty console/terminal windows or whatsoever.

Comment: And just to be clear, `clipup` is a statement *inside* that file.cmd?

Comment: @UweKeim - it's a `Client License Platform migration tool`, considered as a Win32 EXE (Executable application) file developed and available for Windows 10.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - Correct.

Comment: OK, in a console window outside of your program, do this: `SET>d:\temp\outside.txt`, then add the following line to your file.cmd: `SET>d:\temp\inside.txt`, then use your favorite text comparison tool to compare the two, in particular pay attention to the PATH variable.

Comment: Perhaps you are using relative paths in the cmd file, but the current working directory is incorrect when it is run via code. Maybe try with full paths or changing to the correct working directory.

Comment: Side note - I find Microsoft's SysInternals Process Monitor application helps when troubleshooting files not found and permission issues when I can't alter code easily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - I got a Platform issue, `clipup.exe` does exist in `System32` but by default when using `AnyCPU`, instead of `C:\Windows\System32` I am redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` which mean the default platform target is `x86`. I had to change my platform to `x64` for temporary fixed. I will delete this question and ask a very specific question about it instead.

Comment: Good that you located the problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Instead of removing this post, I'll answer and keep it for future researcher.***

This is a common problem when you were trying to access the `System32` in a `x64 bit` Windows OS with your application.

> **NOTICE:** By default when you navigate into your `Project Properties` > `Build` the `Platform Target` is `Any CPU` but the `Prefer 32-bit` is in `checked`.

It means by default when you try to access the `System32` directory, you will be redirect into `SysWOW64` because it's prefer target is `x32 bit`, then you won't be able to access all of the tool you'll probably need.

> **NOTE:** You won't be having this problem in `x32 bit` Windows OS, so as long
>   as your target cpu is `x32` your fine.

**SOLUTION 1: Set your `Platform Target` to `x64`.**

*This solution only works if you prefer to run your application into `x64 bit` Windows OS only.*

Go to your `Project Properties` > `Build` and set the `Platform Target` to `x64`.

**SOLUTION 2: Set your WorkingDirectory. (Works for .Net 4.0 and Newer)**

*This solution is best and works if you prefer to run your application into both `x64 bit` and `x32 bit`Windows OS.*

```
Process process = new Process();

/**This is where the magic happen**/
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem){ //Works for .Net 4.0 and newer
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "sysnative"); //set working directory for x64bit
}else{
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "System32"); //set working directory for x32bit
    //process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;//or use this to set working directory for x32bit
}

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
//process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
```

Using `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` I've check if the system is running on 64bit or 32bit then set the WorkingDirectory to `sysnative` for 64bit and `System32` for 32bit. [Here's](https://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) a link to understand more about `sysnative` directory.